# How does the linker assign anything to ITCMRAM on STM32 H7 series Arm Cortex M MCU?

Tags: linker, arm, embedded, ram, linker-scripts

How does the linker assign anything to `ITCMRAM` on STM32 H7 series Arm Cortex M MCU?

The [linker script provided by ST](https://raw.githubusercontent.com/STMicroelectronics/STM32CubeH7/master/Projects/STM32H735G-DK/Examples/UART/UART_Printf/STM32CubeIDE/STM32H735IGKX_FLASH.ld) has a section defining `ITCMRAM`:

```
/* Memories definition */
MEMORY
{
  ITCMRAM    (xrw)    : ORIGIN = 0x00000000,   LENGTH = 64K
  RAM    (xrw)    : ORIGIN = 0x20000000,   LENGTH = 128K
  ROM    (rx)    : ORIGIN = 0x08000000,   LENGTH = 1024K
}
```

Yet there are no references *anywhere* to `ITCMRAM` that I can find.  Does the linker actually ever use it? If not, what is the point of defining it?

Comment: It does not by default as you see in your linker script.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

To effectively assign anything to this memory, the linker script would need something like this in its `SECTIONS`:

```
  .itcmram :
  {
    . = ALIGN(4);
    KEEP(*(.itcm)) /* or other name(s) */
    . = ALIGN(4);
  } >ITCMRAM
```

The definition in `MEMORY` might simply be a remainder of a general and bigger linker script used as a template, which was reduced to the one you look at.

Comment: Depending on the use, you might like to zero the memory or initialize it.  You need some startup code to support it.  Either to clear the memory on boot or to copy something from flash to the initial state.

Comment: It will only reserve the memory but it will not do anything with the memory. so if you write `int __attribute__((section(".itcmram"))) x = 5;` you will not have 5 there.